# How to store pointers to callback functions with different signatures in an STL container (map<string, func>)?

Tags: c++, c++11, gstreamer

I'm currently in a situation where I want to store function pointers in an `std::map<string, func>` . Specifically, these functions are callback functions which have different signatures, and importantly they have different return types which is the heart of my problem.

For example:

```
// callback 1
GstPadProbeReturn callback_1(GstPad *pad, GstPadProbeInfo *info, gpointer u_data);

// callback 2
GstFlowReturn callback_2(GstPad *pad, GstPadProbeInfo *info, gpointer sharedPtr)

// callback 3
void callback_3(GstElement *element, GstPad *pad, gpointer u_data);

/* somewhere else in the code */
std::map<std::string, functionPtr> cb_map;

map["func1", callback_1];
map["func2", callback_2];
map["func3", callback_3];
```

and so I can pull the callback I want out of the map and connect the callbacks in the code, which with gstreamer can be done in the following way:

```
gst_pad_add_probe(probe_pad, GST_PAD_PROBE_TYPE_BUFFER, callback_1, NULL, NULL);
```

The problem here is callback_1 must match a return type as specified by `gst_pad_add_probe` while other functions can accept void.

I tried several approached but I keep getting stuck at either not being able to store functions of different signatures in `std::map` or not being able to pass `std::function<void>` in the calling function.

I tried the following:

```
template <class F, class... Args>
inline auto FuncWrapper(F &&f) -> decltype(f)
{
  return f;
}

std::map<std::string, std::function<void>()> cb_map;

auto cb1 = FuncWrapper(&callbacks_1);

this->cb_padprobereturn_map.emplace("one", cb1); // doesn't work 
}
```

Apologies if this is not clear, I wasn't sure how to succinctly explain this problem. I'm also not well versed enough in c++ to use things such as `std::variant`

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: How do you call them? Where do you get call arguments?

Comment: So `gst_pad_add_probe` expects a callback of type `GstPadProbeReturn(GstPad*, GstPadProbeInfo*, gpointer)`, but your other callbacks do not have a matching signature. How do you expect such a map (if it was possible) to help with this problem? I don't really see what you are trying to do with it.

Comment: This is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/200806) if ever I saw one.

Comment: You just don't do that. If you find yourself in need of such a thing, you revisit and fix your design, rather than try and bend the type system. The type system is there for a reason.

Comment: The rationale is that I need to be able to specify which callback to call in a gstreamer function from a config (json) file. I realise it's messing with the type system and reeks of bad practices, but unfortunately it's a business requirement. The alternative is having different maps for each different callback signature, which is hard to scale.

Comment: Ask the person who sets the requirement: when one needs to call back the callback, how is one supposed to know which arguments to use? (Using several different maps, each for its own type of callback, is **by far** the most easy to implement, easy to understand, *and scalable* option).

Comment: Does your json dile also tells you which arguments to use for the callback? Can you show an example of such file?

Comment: Sorry about the late response. No, no arguments are specified in the json file, just which callback to link to.

Comment: So how do you know which arguments to use? You write `something = map["foobar"];`. *How do you know what to do next?*

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly a solution provided by me. But it seemed to me like an interesting practice cause I'm also c++ beginner.

Bellow the code to store functions with different signatures in a map.
I wrapped function in a structure func_wraper. Each function can be called using call(...)

```
#include <map>
#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using F1 = std::function<bool(int, long)>;
using F2 = std::function<int(bool, bool)>;
using F3 = std::function<void(long, long)>;

struct func_wraper{
    F1 fun_type1;
    F2 fun_type2;
    F3 fun_type3;

    func_wraper(F1 f) : fun_type1(f), fun_type2(nullptr), fun_type3(nullptr) {}
    func_wraper(F2 f) : fun_type1(nullptr), fun_type2(f), fun_type3(nullptr) {}
    func_wraper(F3 f) : fun_type1(nullptr), fun_type2(nullptr), fun_type3(f) {}

    int getType()
    {
        if (fun_type1 != nullptr)
            return 1;
        if (fun_type2 != nullptr)
            return 2;
        if (fun_type3 != nullptr)
            return 3;
    }

    bool call (int a, long b) {
        return fun_type1(a, b);
    }
    bool call(bool a, bool b) {
        return fun_type2(a, b);
    }
    void call(long a, long b) {
        fun_type3(a, b);
    }

};

bool fun1(int a, long b) { 
    std::cout << "f1" << std::endl;
    return true; 
};
int fun2(bool a, bool b) {
    std::cout << "f2" << std::endl;
    return 1; 
};

void fun3(long a, long b){
    std::cout << "f3" << std::endl;
};

int fun4(long a, long b) { return 1; };

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, func_wraper> cb_map{
        {"type1", F1(fun1)},
        {"type2", F2(fun2)},
        {"type3", F3(fun3)}    
    };

    cb_map.at("type1").call((int) 1, (long) 0.1);
    cb_map.at("type2").call(true, true);
    cb_map.at("type3").call((long) 0.1, (long) 0.2);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
f1
f2
f3
```

Hope it somehow helps you

**UPD.**
You can use std::any but then you should use std::any_cast to cast stored variable in a map to known type

```
template<typename T>
struct func_wrapper {
    T saved_func;

    func_wrapper(T fun) : saved_func(fun) {}

    template<typename... Args>
    auto operator()(Args... args)
    {
        saved_func(args...);
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, std::any> cb_map{
          {"type1", func_wrapper<F1>(fun1)},
          {"type2", func_wrapper<F2>(fun2)},
          {"type3", func_wrapper<F3>(fun3)}
    };

   std::any_cast<func_wrapper<F1>>(cb_map.at("type1"))(1, 0.1);
   std::any_cast<func_wrapper<F2>>(cb_map.at("type2"))(true, true);
   std::any_cast<func_wrapper<F3>>(cb_map.at("type3"))(0.1, 0.2);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the effort you put into this! This does seem quite close to what I'm trying to accomplish. I'll try to use it in my code base and see how it scales.